# Trying to slide away/in a jquery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide

HTML:

```
<div class="col">
    <div href="" target="_blank" class="container backgroundLeft">Mail</div>
    <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/b/" target="_blank" class="map good container">Persoonlijk</a>
    <a href="http://boards.4chan.org/pol/" target="_blank" class="map good container">Werk</
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map{transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".container").on("click", function(e) {
    var currentBox = $(this).siblings(".map").toggleClass("active");
    $(".map.active").not(currentBox).removeClass("active");

    $( ".col" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".map").removeClass("active", 1000);
    });
});
```

Im trying to make it so when you get of .col and the maps go away with a slide right now its instantly.

how it looks right now: https://gyazo.com/8bac8a3eafed610bb66b04c607c7d2e9

They asked for a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbpw93vf/2/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or a code snippet, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean

Comment: we don't see the container and active class, so we are not able to run your code and see behavior

Comment: I edited the post with the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$('.map').on('mouseleave', function({
  $('.map').hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: that only makes it so you have to wait before it goes away.

Comment: I'm sorry but i do not understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want a transition effect when the maps slide